# Some library functions of access not working also code for getting data from one form to another compilation is failing

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command119_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "PrinterFhamyLabel"

Forms!PrinterFhamyLabel.Text59 = Me.JOBNum

End Sub
```

I have two forms:

Form PrinterFhamyInput has textbox JOBNum Form PrinterFhamyLabel has textbox Text59

I will enter data in textbox JOBNum in Form PrinterFhamyInput and click a button on the PrinterFhamyInput form, which should open Form PrinterFhamyLabel with textbox Text59 populated with data from field JOBNum.

At the table level :

PrinterFhamyInput has a field called JOB# and PrinterFhamyLabel has a field called JOB# (Images attached).

I want to input JOB#, Description and QTY in PrinterFhamyInput form and click the button "PrintLabel" and it opens Label Form with these three inputs populated. I enter the date and then print label.
[image]
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Heed @June7's advice, and I'd even go a notch further and warmly recommend *against* using underscores - Both Access and VBA use underscores in identifiers to very specific ends, and consistent `PascalCase` is much easier to read and work with. That said if you *need* to have special characters in a name, you need to "quote" that identifier with square brackets: `[JOB#]`.

Comment: Intellisense definitely works for me. It should work in a brand new db with only the 4 default libraries. Why do you need to duplicate data?

Comment: so the purpose of the second form is to print a label for manufacturing, it is critical to the process. The second form has lot of other inputs. I just need JOBnum in Text59.

Comment: Then why not open form filtered to desired record and bind textbox to field JobNum? Text59 is not a field, it is a textbox control. Not the correct syntax referencing form to trigger intellisense. See my answer.

Comment: there is no other way, what i am trying to do is extremely simple. However I am close to a layman in vba, so I dont know basic syntax etc. I know this isn't a complex thing to program.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: I dont think i explained my question very clearly, what you are suggesting is not what i need at all

Comment: First of all, forms are intended for screen display, reports are for printing. Printing a form can be done but not as easily as report. If Job# is record in table then open form or report to that record. Looks like your form is set to open only to New Record row. Enter record, commit to table, open report for printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form_PrinterFhamy_Label.` should provoke intellisense popup tips. Look at form and report names in the VBA editor - they all have a prefix. That is the name for VBA purpose to provoke intellisense. If code is behind the form, can use `Me.` alias.

Open form or report filtered to desired record and have textbox bound to field JobNum:

```
Private Sub Command119_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "PrinterFhamyLabel", , , "[Job#]=" & Me.JobNum
End Sub
```

If JobNum is text type field:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "PrinterFhamyLabel", , , "[Job#]='" & Me.JobNum & "'"`

Suggest you do some basic research on use of OpenForm/OpenReport method.

Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. If used, enclose name in [ ]. JobNum better than Job#. Also, camelCase or PascalCase is easier to read than ALLCAPS.

Comment: DoCmd.OpenForm "PrinterFhamyLabel", , , "JobNum='" & Me.JobNum & "'"     Should this be  --->>>   DoCmd.OpenForm "PrinterFhamyLabel", , , "Text59='" & Me.JobNum & "'"  Both Text59 and JOBNum are textboxes.

Comment: No. Text59 is not a field in RecordSource. It is a textbox on form. JobNum may be a textbox but I presume there is also a field in table.

Comment: if i want to copy multiple fields?

Comment: More textboxes bound to data. Edit question to show example of table data. It is not clear what you are trying to do. Why would you have to pass data to a form as opposed to having a RecordSource and bound textboxes?

Comment: You are correct, Text59 is not a field in RecordSource, the field name in Table for it is JOB# which same in the other table as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command119_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm "PrinterFhamylabel"

Forms![PrinterFhamyLabel].JOB = Me.JOBNum

Me.JOBNum.SetFocus

End Sub
```

this solved it, thanks to @June7 for all the help and guidance.